# Assembly 8086 Pressing two scan codes at the same time

Tags: assembly, keyboard, x86, x86-16, dosbox

I'm trying to write a code that changes the screen to full screen mode. The problem is that I run the programming in dosbox (windows) so I have to make the dosbox become full screened. I did a research and I found out that by pressing `ALT+ENTER` dosbox becomes full screen. The problem with that is that I don't want the user to change to full screen, and I want the program itself to do it.

After another research I found `int 16h, 05h`. I've set `Cl` to the ASCII value of the `ENTER`  button (`0Dh`). Then I set in `CH` the scan code of `ALT` (`38h`). Then I tested it and yet it didn't turn into full screen. I did a check to make sure the scan code of `ALT` is working, by changing `CL` to another char and it worked, so that's not the problem. Then I tried to change `CH` to `ALT+ENTER` (`0Ah`) and it still didn't work.

I think the problem is that `int 16h, 05` sends a scan code and an ASCII char, and I try to refer to an ASCII char as its button.

Is there a way to press 2 scan codes at the same time? (Or make `ALT` become held down and then using `int 16h,05h` to  press on the `ENTER` key?)

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that the GUI only captures `ALT+ENTER` when sent from the host OS, not the emulated OS.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson So I thought maybe it's possible to use int 9h to trick it, but I have no clue how to do that, or if it's even possible

Comment: I don't think there's anyway for a program running inside DOSBox to tell it switch to full screen. Simulating keystrokes within DOSBox isn't going to work. As Joachim said, the ALT-ENTER keystroke has has to come from the OS that DOSBox is running under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I set in CH the scan code of ALT (38h). ... I did a check to make sure the scan code of ALT is working, by changing CL to another char and it worked, so that's not the problem.

The BIOS function that simulates keypresses will never deal with ALT the way you imagine. ALT is just a special key that mofifies the ASCII and SCAN codes of other keys, it will never show up by itself in any part of the encoding. Setting `CH` to 38h won't work.

---

Getting the DOSBOX window full screen is a **Windows** operation. You can only do this from Windows programming code. You can't do this from within a DOS program running within the DOSBOX emulator.

---

On the idea to simulate ALT-ENTER.
In the good old days of Windows 3.1 you had a PIF configuration file that allowed you to specify wether certain key combinations would be treated by Windows or by the DOS program running within Windows. With the correct selection made, your DOS program could then recieve the ALT-ENTER key.

Maybe at this point you could try to EXEC a true Windows program to maximize the DOS program's window.